# how can i use a function directly in commandline in python?

Tags: python

for example:
my command line after execution of a program has to be like this:

```
perfect(44) #using the defined function in the output screen.(44) or any other number
```

and the output should be:

```
false
```

this the code i have tried but in this i cannot use the funcion in the command line.

```
def factors(n):
    factorlist = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            factorlist = factorlist + [i]
    print factorlist
    return factorlist
```

def perfect(n):
    factorlist = factors(n)
    if sum(factorlist) == n:
        return True
    else :
        return False

n = int(raw_input())
print(perfect(n))

Comment: Do you have the functions stored in a file? Or on command line?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the path where you have the `.py` file located. Start the python interpreter in interactive mode by the following command:

```
python -i filename.py
```

By doing this, you should be able to access all functions inside your `filename.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the following lines to your python script to call a function when the script is loaded.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(perfect(int(sys.argv[1])))
```

You can then call it like:

```
python myscript.py 44
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to the file directory and run the command from command line.

```
python -c "import modulename"
```

here `modulename`  is your `file_name.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a 3rd party package, check out [Google's Fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md).

```
pip install fire
```

Modify your code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fire import Fire

def factors(n):
    factorlist = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            factorlist = factorlist + [i]
    print factorlist
    return factorlist


def perfect(n):
    factorlist = factors(n)
    if sum(factorlist) == n:
        return True
    else :
        return False

# n = int(raw_input())
# print(perfect(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Fire(perfect)
```

Make sure your file is executable if on Mac or Linux (sorry, have no idea if you have to do that on Windows). Assuming your code is in a file named `perfect`:

```
chmod +x perfect
```

If the file is in your path, you should now be able to call it like this:

```
$ perfect 44
[1, 2, 4, 11, 22]
False
```